# Key equivalent delete doesn't work in cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have 2 buttons, + and - that is add and delete buttons which works just fine, that is when I click on them, record is created or deleted. I add key equivalent + for the + button, and that works just fine.

However, I am trying to add **delete** key equivalent for the - button and strange thing is happening. If I click on the delete key, record is not deleted. However, if I click backspace button, record is deleted. Needles to say, if i change the key equivalent to backspace button, record is deleted only if I press backspace key, if I press delete key, it doesn't delete the record.

On the end, just to mention that when I add backspace key equivalent, the icon displayed is ⌫ and the delete key has ⌦ icon.

I am woking on iMac (Early 2008) and I have standard aluminium english keyboard.

Anyone can help me to delete record with pressing the delete key?

Comment: Based on the icons, it sounds like Backspace is what you want, and your Delete key is a forward-delete.

Comment: So your advice is to leave the backspace as delete button? I guess I am not the only one with this type of keyboard. But what makes me worry is that users will expect record to be deleted when they hit delete key, not the backspace. Or I am wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see your keyboard. :( But the key above the backslash key, whatever that is, is the one that everyone will expect to use here.

Comment: Mine is  the second one: https://markinns.com/archive/apple-keyboards.html

Comment: So basically most users will be able to delete the record with the delete key, the others will have to figure out that they should use the backspace key, is my assumption right?

Comment: Despite the word Delete on the first one, it is the Backspace key and that is the shortcut you should use. In other words, whatever key deletes the previous character, use that one.

Comment: What is record?  Is that a record of data appearing in an instance of NSTableView or a music record?  Why is it not countable?  If it's the latter, why don't you subclass NSTableView?

Comment: @matt, please go ahead and write this as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks for your clarification.

Comment: @El Tomato, the record is  data appearing in the instance of nstableview. No one said that record is not countable. Please re-read the question and the comments that we exchanged with matt.

Comment: Actually, subclassing NSTableView won't solve the problem you are addressing.  That's a normal behavior for Mac OS X.  The delete key located above 'return' is the one to click on when you trigger an action in a list.  The delete key located next to 'end' is used to delete a letter of text.  Clicking on the latter won't let you trigger an action when a table row is selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the icons, it sounds like Backspace is what you want, and your Delete key is a forward-delete. Some users will have a (backwards) Delete key where your Backspace key is, but the label is irrelevant; they do the same thing and this is what users will expect to use to delete a record. Many users will not even have a forward-delete key, so it would be most unwise to make it a shortcut.